# Missing "Google app script" under new

Tags: google-apps-script

When I go to my google drive and click "new" I get a "google app script" option, however, when I do the same on another account, I don't get the option.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I got it.

1) Go to Google Drive and click New > More > Connect more apps.
2) When the "Connect apps to Drive" window appears, type "script" into the search box and press Enter.
3) Click Connect next to the listing for Google Apps Script.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone

I don't recall doing that on the other two accounts I have standalone scripts in.  Whatever.